# Problema Simples (Calculadora em Java - Switch)

Tags: java

Galera estou com muitos problemas em relação á um trabalho a ser entregue amanha, algúem pode ajudar ?

EDIT: fiz a base, mas estou tendo problemas para adicionar o switch ao código e concluir a calculadora, podem me dizer como faço pelo menos a parte de somar e a parte de introduzir o numero? seria com scanner ?

> Construir uma Calculadora em Java que possua as seguintes funcionalidades:
>
> ```
>     Menu:
>       (1) - Inserir valor inicial
>       (2) - Somar
>       (3) - Subtrair
>       (4) - Multiplicar
>       (5) - Dividir
>       (6) - Potencia
>       (7) - Inverter Sinal
>       (8) - Limpar Resultado
> ```
>
> Deve-se implementar 2 classes:
>        1) Principal, contém a parte de interação com o usuário (interface e entrada de dados),
>        2) Calculadora, contém a implementação dos métodos responsáveis pelo cálculo em sí (somar, dividir, multiplicar, etc).

Classe Principal:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // menu
        System.out.println("CALCULADORA \n");
        System.out.println("Resultado: \n");
        System.out.println("Menu:");
        System.out.println(" (1) - Inserir valor inicial;");
        System.out.println(" (2) - Somar;");
        System.out.println(" (3) - Subtrair;");
        System.out.println(" (4) - Multiplicar;");
        System.out.println(" (5) - Dividir;");
        System.out.println(" (6) - Potencia;");
        System.out.println(" (7) - Inverter Sinal;");
        System.out.println(" (8) - Limpar Resultado;");

        //Principal p = new Principal();
        //p.limparTela();

    }

    public void limparTela() {
        for (int i=0; i< 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Classe Calculadora

```
public class Calculadora {
    // Atributos
    private Double resultado = 0.0;

    // Metodos
    public void inserirValorInicial(Double valor) { }
    public Double obterResultado() {    return 0.0; }
    public void somar(Double valor) {   }
    public void subtrair(Double valor) {    }
    public void multiplicar(Double valor) { }
    public void dividir(Double valor) { }
    public void inverterSinal() {   }
    public void potencia(int potencia) {    }
    public void limpar() {  }
}
```

Comment: Qual é sua duvida? Edite a pergunta e explique onde está tendo duvidas.

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida, você está tendo algum erro?

Comment: fiz a base, mas estou tendo problemas para adicionar o switch ao código e concluir a calculadora, podem me dizer como faço pelo menos a parte de somar e a parte de introduzir o numero? seria com scanner ?

Answer (score 1):

Para ler os números podes usar o `Scanner`

```
Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
int escolha = leitor.nextInt();

double a = leitor.nextDouble();

double b = leitor.nextDouble();

switch(escolha){
case 1:
soma(a,b);
break;
}
```

função `soma`

```
public static void soma(double a,double b){
     System.out.println("Resultado = " + (a+b));
}
```